# Socket.BeginSend show send error after 1 minute

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient, asyncsocket

I use Socket class (async) for a client app.

my server is a hardware but I use hercules(a tcp/udp server/client provider software) for test.

when I close server port with hercules(or similar app) my client application pay attention quickly but when I remove network cable occured Disconnect(client) function after 1 or 2 minutes.

```
public static void Send(Socket client, String data)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None,
                    new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);              
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Disconnect(client);
            }

        }
```

Comment: What is the exact problem here? If remove network cable, Windows try to find a connection and monitor existing network interfaces, it takes a time

Comment: Thank you, Is there any way to increase this operation ?

Comment: Try to check this thread https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/29550/detecting-socket-disconnect-in-net

Comment: reliably detecting a broken socket is impossible when done passively; AFAIK the *only* way you can do this is using an active ping/pong and tracking whether you've had a pong in an expected timeframe (i.e. have a timer that checks for overdue pongs intermittently, and severs the connection if it looks suspect); as a side note - if using `BeginSend`, you need to be careful, because it can be `SendCallback` that receives the exception, not your `Send` method